# Replace NULL Value with Where condition value

Tags: mysql

Any idea how do i Replace NULL Value with Where condition 'John Miller' value

```
select 
  t2.creatorfullname, 
  count(distinct(t1.ticketmaskid)) as total
from 
  swtickets t1 join swticketauditlogs t2 
    on t1.ticketid = t2.ticketid 
where 
  from_unixtime(t2.dateline) > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
  and FIND_IN_SET(t2.creatorfullname,'John Miller') > 0 
  and t2.actionmsg like '%Ticket status changed from: % to: Closed%'  
  and totalreplies > 0;
```

**Table**

```
+-----------------+-------+
| creatorfullname | total |
+-----------------+-------+
| NULL            |     0 |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (1.47 sec)
```

**I would like to get the following output:**

```
+-----------------+-------+
| creatorfullname | total |
+-----------------+-------+
| John Miller     |     0 |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (1.47 sec)
```

What if the where condition has multiple names? QUESTION UPDATED

```
select 
  t2.creatorfullname, 
  count(distinct(t1.ticketmaskid)) as total 
from 
  swtickets t1 join swticketauditlogs t2 
    on t1.ticketid = t2.ticketid 
where 
  from_unixtime(t2.dateline) > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
  and FIND_IN_SET(t2.creatorfullname,'John Miller, Alicia Lee, Steve Caleb') > 0 
  and t2.actionmsg like '%Ticket status changed from: % to: Closed%' 
  and totalreplies > 0;
```

```
+-----------------+-------+
| creatorfullname | total |
+-----------------+-------+
| NULL            |     0 |
| Alicia Lee      |     5 |
| Steve Caleb     |    43 |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (1.47 sec)
```

**I want it to be:**

```
+-----------------+-------+
| creatorfullname | total |
+-----------------+-------+
| John Miller     |     0 |
| Alicia Lee      |     5 |
| Steve Caleb     |    43 |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (1.47 sec)
```

Comment: -1: Most of that query is not related to this problem. This question won't be very useful for anyone else.

Comment: Is John Miller's name in this list? `SELECT DISTICT creatorfullname FROM swticketauditlogs`

Comment: Is just that John Miller is not there on that specific day (INTERVAL 1 DAY) Coz not everyone log on daily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT IFNULL(t2.creatorfullname,'John Miller'), 
    COUNT(distinct(t1.ticketmaskid)) AS total
FROM swtic .....
```

Comment: What if there are more than one creatorfullname. Question updated

Answer (score 0):

Add an `IFNULL` check in your statement. `t2.creatorfullname` is `NULL` and `FIND_IN_SET` evaluates to nULL completely

```
select t2.creatorfullname, count(distinct(t1.ticketmaskid)) as total from swtickets t1 join swticketauditlogs t2 on t1.ticketid = t2.ticketid where from_unixtime(t2.dateline) > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) and FIND_IN_SET(IFNULL(t2.creatorfullname,'x'),'John Miller') > 0 and t2.actionmsg like '%Ticket status changed from: % to: Closed%' and totalreplies > 0;
```

Comment: ERROR 1582 (42000): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: Sorry, in MYsql its IFNULL . Mea Culpa. updating answer now.

Comment: @user1204671: Based on your question update, My answer is still useful :)

Comment: FIND_IN_SET(IFNULL(t2.creatorfullname,'x'),'John Miller') > 0  should evaluate as 0 for NULL name

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an outer join between a table containing your list of names and your `swticketauditlogs` table:

```
SELECT
  t3.creatorfullname,
  COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ticketmaskid) total
FROM
  swtickets t1 JOIN swticketauditlogs t2 USING (ticketid) NATURAL RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT 'John Miller' creatorfullname
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Alicia Lee'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Steve Caleb'
  ) t3
WHERE
  t2.dateline > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIME - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND t2.actionmsg LIKE '%Ticket status changed from: % to: Closed%' 
  AND totalreplies > 0
GROUP BY
  t3.creatorfullname
```

Comment: using t3 Looks promising but unfortunately  Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Comment: @user1204671: What was the warning?  Can you post some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: Warning (Code 1292): Incorrect datetime value: '22:00:32'

Comment: SELECT t3.creatorfullname, COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ticketmaskid) total FROM swtickets t1 JOIN (swticketauditlogs t2 NATURAL RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 'Alicia Lee' creatorfullname UNION ALL SELECT 'Steve Caleb' UNION ALL SELECT 'John Miller') t3) USING (ticketid) WHERE from_unixtime(t2.dateline) > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND t2.actionmsg LIKE '%Ticket status changed from: % to: Closed%' AND totalreplies > 0 GROUP BY t3.creatorfullname;

Comment: i modified your query to get rid the warning but still only show asAlicia Lee      |     5 |
| Steve Caleb     |    43

Comment: basically John Miller is not available in creatorfullname but i wish to display it as creatorfullname 0

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GROUP BY`.

If you are wanting to filter by certain users, keep the field in the `WHERE` clause:
(EDITED - `LEFT JOIN`)

```
select t2.creatorfullname
     , count(distinct(t1.ticketmaskid)) as total
from swticketauditlogs t2 
left join swtickets t1 on t1.ticketid = t2.ticketid 
where from_unixtime(t2.dateline) > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
  and FIND_IN_SET(t2.creatorfullname,'John Miller, Alicia Lee, Steve Caleb') > 0
  and t2.actionmsg like '%Ticket status changed from: % to: Closed%'
  and totalreplies > 0
group by
    t2.creatorfullname;
```

Comment: i only want specific users. so your solution wont work

Comment: It doesnt work. basically the scenario was Alicia Lee, Steve Caleb are in creatorfullname column but John Miller is not in creatorfullname, so since John Miller is not available in the column, i wish to display it as John Miller 0.

Comment: If John Miller is not in the database, then your data is bad.

Comment: Is just that John Miller is not there on that specific day (INTERVAL 1 DAY) Coz not everyone log on daily.

Comment: The query now uses a left join. Can you try it? This is hard without using something like an sqlfiddle